# DB Transaction in Laravel lexical variable error

Tags: database, laravel

I'm currently using DB-Transaction and it throws Lexical variable error 
attached here is my code:

```
 DB::transaction(function ($request) use ($request) {
            $salesman = new Salesman([ 
            'operation_id'      => $request->get('operation_id'),  
            'warehouse_id'      => $request->get('warehouse_id'),
            'salesman_name'     => $request->get('salesman_name'),  
            'address'           => $request->get('address'),  
            'contact_number'    => $request->get('contact_number'),  
            'email_address'     => $request->get('email_address'), 
            'area_id'           => 'pending',     
            ]);
        $salesman->save();
   });
        return view('salesman.index');
 }
```

Comment: What's the full error? And you don't need to pass `$request` as an argument to the anonymous function. `use ($request)` is sufficient.

Comment: It works I remove $request in function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working now after I remove the $request parameter in function

```
 DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
                $salesman = new Salesman([ 
                'operation_id'      => $request->get('operation_id'),  
                'warehouse_id'      => $request->get('warehouse_id'),
                'salesman_name'     => $request->get('salesman_name'),  
                'address'           => $request->get('address'),  
                'contact_number'    => $request->get('contact_number'),  
                'email_address'     => $request->get('email_address'), 
                'area_id'           => 'pending',     
                ]);
            $salesman->save();
       });
            return view('salesman.index');
     }
```